# Separate columns into 2

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

I have a df with a column:

| Column A |
| --- |
| 100_1-A-C-F/G |
| 200_2-B-D-G/F |

100_1 is the sample numbers
where A/B is the different drug
C/D is the different method
F/G OR G/F is the different technique

How do I separate the column to look like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 100_1 | A-C-F/G |
| 200_2 | B-D-G/F |

Thanks

I use separate function and I selected (sep =  "_")
however, this still includes the sample number:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1-A-C-F/G |
| 200 | 2-B-D-G/F |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `separate`, but you need to use a regular expression in `sep`:

```
df %>% 
  separate(`Column A`, into = c("Column A", "Column B"), sep="(?<=\\d)-")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  `Column A` `Column B`
  <chr>      <chr>     
1 100_1      A-C-F/G   
2 200_2      B-D-G/F
```

Input

```
df = tibble(
  "Column A" = c("100_1-A-C-F/G", "200_2-B-D-G/F")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sub()` here for a base R option:

```r
df$B <- sub(".*?-(.*?)", "\\1", df$A)
df$A <- sub("-.*", "", df$A)
df

      A       B
1 100_1 A-C-F/G
2 200_2 B-D-G/F
```